# ASP.NET MVC Controls & CSS

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to apply css on my html.dropdownlist with a regular html select list css. Can anyone show me how to go about doing this & where am I going wrong with this

this is what i have right now..

```
<div id="container">
   Months &nbsp; <%=Html.DropDownList("dllMonths", new SelectList(new List<string>() { "January", 
    "Feburary", "March", "April", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"}, ViewData["Month"]), new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" })%>

    Events &nbsp;<%=Html.DropDownList("dllEvents", new SelectList(new List<string>() { "Camp Events", 
    "Weekly Events", "All Events"}, ViewData["Event"]), new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" })%>

</div>
```

and this is the css that i am trying to apply
http://www.emblematiq.com/projects/niceforms/demo/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part of your code where you use an anonymous object to set html properties, change it to this:

```
new { onchange = "this.form.submit();", @class="selectlist" }
```

The @ symbol allows you to use a property name that is a reserved word. You can also add style="" if you want inline styling (but you probably don't).

Also, you don't need to new up SelectList, there's an overload on Html.DropDownList() that lets you pass those same values.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me all you need is to include in the head of your site master. These two entries:-

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/niceforms.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="../../Content/niceforms-default.css" />
```

Then on the form element in which your code resides place the attribute `class="niceform"`.

Of course this assumes you are using the standard content folder for css and Scripts folder for JS files.

I can't really see a specific MVC issue here except if you are using a Html.BeginForm.
In which case you need:-

```
Html.BeginForm("action", "controller", FormMethod.Post, new {@class="niceform"})
```

Answer (score 1):

hey if anyone needs to know for future reference .. this is how i did it..

```
%using (Html.BeginForm("Calendar", "Calendar", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "niceform" }))
  { %>
<div id="container">
   Months &nbsp; <%=Html.DropDownList("dllMonths", new SelectList(new List<string>() { "January", 
    "Feburary", "March", "April", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"}, ViewData["Month"]), new { onchange = "this.form.submit();", @class = "width_320" })%>

    Events &nbsp;<%=Html.DropDownList("dllEvents", new SelectList(new List<string>() { "Camp Events", 
    "Weekly Events", "All Events"}, ViewData["Event"]), new { onchange = "this.form.submit();", @class = "width_320" })%>
    &nbsp;<%=Html.SubmitImage("SearchAll", "~/imagens/imgsearch.jpg")%>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Html.DropDownList("ddl-id", Model.SomeListForDDl, new {@class="className"})
```